# Google indexes the page using the domain alias

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I have a Drupal 8 page which is indexed from Google without any error. The front page is a node configured as a front page in the *Basic site* settings (admin/config/system/site-information) using the path alias /front or de/heim.

The point is that the path alias for the front page should be the root (e.g. example.com) which is it. So, everything is working fine if I navigate the page.

Why is the path alias shown in Google search results, and not the root domain?  It shows example.com/en/front or example.com/de/heim, not example.com.

I have never seen this problem before using Drupal 6 or Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what page Google finds first, I guess. So, I do now know.

> Why is the alias shown in Google search results, and not the root domain?

However in order to overcome this, you would have used the [global redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) in Drupal 7, which has been merged with [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect). I have not tried it, but if it an exact port it should still be able to.

> Checks if the current URL is the same as the site_frontpage and
>   redirects to the frontpage if there is a match.

Comment: Yes, it does do that, there's still an inconsistency in core, because if you do have a node as frontpage then it will automatically add a canonical path to /home, which isn't correct but that's IMHO something that should be fixed in core.

Comment: @Berdir that is exactly what it does.

Comment: The second "weird" thing is that it actually makes a correct redirect when using the sites default language front page setting. But it does not do it when using multiple languages. Anyway the indexing is not working correctly because of the <link rel="canonical" href="/en" /> .

Comment: Ok, then I think you're looking for https://www.drupal.org/node/2704213, that issue should fix a number of issues that currently exist with those redirect features on multilingual sites

Comment: Looks like the right issue in progress. Thanks Berdir!

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2704213 is now patched and tested so I think the case is closed. Nice job @Berdir and Drupal community.